# PHYTON: _tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-canvas

My 9 year-old son is studying Python and he faced below problem in his code (bubble breaker game):

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "M:\Yandex disk\YandexDisk\ДЕТКИ\python modules\Bubble Blaster.py", line 55, in <module>
move_bubbles()
File "M:\Yandex disk\YandexDisk\ДЕТКИ\python modules\Bubble Blaster.py", line 48, in 
move_bubbles
c.move(bub_id[i], -bub_speed[i], 0)
File "C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 
2949, in move
self.tk.call((self._w, 'move') + args)
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"*
```

I've rechecked the whole code twice but can't find any mistake.

Here is the whole code:

```
from tkinter import *
HEIGHT = 1080
WIDTH = 1920
window = Tk()
window.title('Bubble Blaster')
c = Canvas(window, width=WIDTH, height=HEIGHT, bg='darkblue')
c.pack()
ship_id = c.create_polygon(5, 5, 5, 25, 30, 15, fill='red')
ship_id2 = c.create_oval(0, 0, 30, 30, outline='red')
SHIP_R = 15
MID_X = WIDTH / 2
MID_Y = HEIGHT / 2
c.move(ship_id, MID_X, MID_Y)
c.move(ship_id2, MID_X, MID_Y)
SHIP_SPD = 10
def move_ship(event):
    if event.keysym == 'Up':
        c.move(ship_id, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
        c.move(ship_id2, 0, -SHIP_SPD)
    elif event.keysym == 'Down':
        c.move(ship_id, 0, SHIP_SPD)
        c.move(ship_id2, 0, SHIP_SPD)
    elif event.keysym == 'Left':
        c.move(ship_id, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
        c.move(ship_id2, -SHIP_SPD, 0)
    elif event.keysym == 'Right':
        c.move(ship_id, SHIP_SPD, 0)
        c.move(ship_id2, SHIP_SPD, 0)
c.bind_all('<Key>', move_ship)
from random import randint
bub_id = list()
bub_r = list()
bub_speed = list()
MIN_BUB_R = 10
MAX_BUB_R = 30
MAX_BUB_SPD = 10
GAP = 100
def create_bubble():
    x = WIDTH + GAP
    y = randint(0, HEIGHT)
    r = randint(MIN_BUB_R, MAX_BUB_R)
    id1 = c.create_oval(x - r, y - r, x + r, y + r, outline='white')
    bub_id.append(id1)
    bub_r.append(r)
    bub_speed.append(randint(1, MAX_BUB_SPD))
def move_bubbles():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)):
        c.move(bub_id[i], -bub_speed[i], 0)
from time import sleep, time
BUB_CHANCE = 10
#MAIN GAME LOOP
while True:
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
    move_bubbles()
    window.update()
    sleep(0.01)
def get_coords(id_num):
    pos = c.coords(id_num)
    x = (pos[0] + pos[2])/2
    y = (pos[1] + pos[3])/2
    return x, y
def del_bubble(I):
    del bub_r[I]
    del bub_speed[I]
    c.delete(bub_id[i])
    del bub_id[I]
def clean_up_bubs():
    for i in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        x, y = get_coords(bub_id[I])
        if x < -GAP:
            del_bubble(I)
#MAIN GAME LOOP
while True:
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
    move_bubbles()
    clean_up_bubs()
    window.update()
    sleep(0.01)
from math import sqrt
def distance(id1, id2):
    x1, y1 = get_coords(id1)
    x2, y2 = get_coords(id2)
    return sqrt((x2 - x1)**2 + (y2 - y1)**2)
def collision():
    points = 0
    for bub in range(len(bub_id)-1, -1, -1):
        if distance(ship_id2, bub_id[bub]) < (SHIP_R + bub_r[bub]):
            points += (bub_r[bub] + bub_speed[bub])
            del_bubble(bub)
    return points
score = 0
#MAIN GAME LOOP
while True:
    if randint(1, BUB_CHANCE) == 1:
        create_bubble()
    move_bubbles()
    clean_up_bubs()
    score += collision()
    print(score)
    window.update()
    sleep(0.01)
```

What is causing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Major mistakes:

1. no main loop

```
from tkinter import *
root = Tk()
root.mainloop()
```

https://tkdocs.com/tutorial/eventloop.html

2. all loops inside the main loop are created with the .after method
   https://tkdocs.com/shipman/universal.html
3. when the window is closed, while cycles continue to work, so an error pops up `_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!canvas"*`
4. and little things

   c.delete(bub_id[i]) The variable "i" is not defined in the function.

```
x, y = get_coords(bub_id[I])
        if x < -GAP:
            del_bubble(I)
```

in this function does not define a large "I".